# What are the differences between logical design and physical design?

Tags: system-design

I can't understand the difference between logical design and physical design. Can you explain the differences between them like you can list 5 differences?

Comment: More context required.  And what does "[list 5]" refer to? Is that relevant? On its own it is meaningless.

Comment: As an example a logical design does not contain any implementation details. A physical design for SQL Server will not work on Oracle. A logical design can work on both Oracle and SQL Server because it doesn't have any implementation details. A physical design can actually be used to create a database. A logical design can't

Answer (score 0):

We usually come up with logical design at high level, using straw-man kind of diagram which you can do in a whiteboard or powerpoint, whereas the physical diagram we use any standard UML diagram based on the need.

The requirements will be input to the logical diagram, for physical diagram - logical diagram will be the input.

The logical design is more conceptual and abstract than the physical design. In the logical design, you look at the logical relationships among the objects. In the physical design, you look at the most effective way of storing and retrieving the objects. Your design should be oriented toward the needs of the end users.

More details: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/server.816/a76994/logical.htm#:~:text=The%20logical%20design%20is%20more,needs%20of%20the%20end%20users](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/server.816/a76994/logical.htm#:%7E:text=The%20logical%20design%20is%20more,needs%20of%20the%20end%20users).